# htaccess sport links redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Need to redirect set of hundred or so links from one domain to another. This is my current code (not working):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.onedomain.info/$1/staticword($2.*) [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://otherdomain.com/$1/staticword($2.*) [R=301,L]
```

Redirect domains themsleves is a no-brainer and that's correct I think, then I too think that $1 is correctly - cuz $1 is a variable for 12 different words for sport categories (like soccer or hockey), sometimes there is one word, sometimes the other (but ofc it should be the same, so this is why I have that $1 there - correct me if I am wrong but this could work I think...).

Problem is that after that there is one static word which is not changing (is same all the time in every link - it's something like "watch"...) BUT after that word there can be absolutely ANYTHING which I tried to solve by ($2.*) but it's wrong for some reason.

Can you help please? Thanks!

Comment: THere are many problems in your code but before I can correct them I request you to provide sample of old and new links.

Comment: Current links looks like that for example (one of the soccer matches): `http://onedomain.info/soccer/watchfe27789-mexico-vs-trinidad-and-tobago-gold-cup` -- "watch" never changes and "fe27789" is identificator which is unique for every link, same as that "mexico vs trinidad" -- Need to switch to:
`http://otherdomain.com/soccer/watchfe27789-mexico-vs-trinidad-and-tobago-gold-cup` -- it should work only for links in this URL form (have other types of internal links - for example onedomain.info/something so dont want them to be redirected, cant use any of the general "domain to domain" redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP_HOST if to match domain names only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.onedomain\.info$ [NC]
# On the left hand we match the rest and on the right we redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(staticword.*)/?$ http://otherdomain.com/$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Note that I am using 302, because you want to test it first before change it to 301 so your browser does not get cached with it until you are sure it's working as you want it to.

So given your example `http://onedomain.info/soccer/watchfe27789-mexico-vs-trinidad-and-tobago-gold-cu‌​p`, the rule would be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP_HOST if to match domain names only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.onedomain\.info$ [NC]
# On the left hand we match the rest and on the right we redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(watchfe27789.*)/?$ http://otherdomain.com/$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks man! (only note that `fe27789` wasn't supposed to be there, cuz its different every time - it's unique ID which is changing for every different link, but when I reduced that part to `(watch.*)` only, it's all working perfectly, great job...!)

Comment: @Mordor glad it works for you, that's OK, I was using it just as an example for you to see how to apply it.